# Simple Rspec test failing from Michael Hartl RoR Tuotiral

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am a total neophyte and I am learning Ruby on Rails with the tutorial from Michael Hartl. I am on chapter 3 and the Rspec test for the about page is failing (while the exact same test is not failing for the home and help pages).

The error I am getting when running `$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` is:

```
Failures:

1) Static pages About page should have the content 'About Us'←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mvisit 'static_pages/about'←[0m←[31mURI::InvalidURIError←[0m:←[31mthe scheme http does not accept registry part: www.example.com:80static_pages (or bad hostname?)←[0m←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m Finished in 0.0776 seconds←[31m3 examples, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:23←[0m ←[36m# Static pages About page should have the content 'About Us'←[0m
```

When accessing `http://localhost:3000/static_pages/about` the page loads and I can see "About Us" in big H1 letters.

**spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit 'static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb:**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/about"
end
```

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

**app/views/about.html.erb:**

```
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
  with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
  is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

Comment: Could you add your `Gemfile`, and `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I notice you're missing the initial `/` in the failing test:

```
visit 'static_pages/about'
```

vs

```
visit '/static_pages/help'
```

Comment: Spot on, crazy distraction!

Comment: Nice one, just got stuck in the exact some place for hour and a half for the exact same reason. Ughh